# What is ABecho command line in Teamviewer Package

Tags: command-line, source-packages

I convert a debian package to tgz package using `alien -t` .

Then , i browse this new package to inspect some scripts :

One of script includes this code:

```
ABecho "teamviewer" "run teamviewer directly"
  echo "   You can just extract the tar.gz package and run 'teamviewer' without installation."
```

`echo` is clear : it is used to display messages on console . However , What is `ABecho` ? Known that i looked for an executable file with this name in package and i don't found it .

## I Guess :

It seems that it's such as `echo`. However , it supports more than one argument , Each argument is a message that will be printed alone (for each line , one message=argument)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Googling for `"function abecho"`, I [found this](http://www.rhock.com.br/programas/LINUX/Teamviewer9/tv_bin/script/tvw_aux):

```
function ABecho()
{
  printf "\E[1m %-30s \E[0m %s \n" "$1" "$2"
}
```

It's formatted output. Bold first variable, up-to 30 spaces (depending on the length of the first variable) and the the second in normal. It's a method of keeping the second column a constant distance out, rather than using `column`. Here are some examples I ran through it to highlight the constant width of the first column.

```
 cheese                          string 
 cheesey                         string 
 cheesey poptart                 string 
 cheesey poptart bananahammock   string
```